# measure preserving transformation question

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I want to prove exercise 4.3.5 of Brin & Stuck

Let $T$ be a measure preserving transformation of measure space $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and let $f\in L^1(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ satisfy $f(T(x))\leq f(x)$ for a.e. $x$.

Prove that $f(T(x))= f(x)$ for a.e. $x$.

My (wrong) attempt (mentioned by John B.) :

$$
f(T(x))\leq f(x),f\in L^1(X,\mathcal{B},\mu) \implies \int_Xf(T(x))d\mu\leq \int_Xf(x)d\mu\leq \int_X|f(x)|d\mu<\infty
$$
The measure preserving of $T$ on $\mu$ means $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}$, $  \mu(T^{-1}(B))=\mu(B)$ for a.e $x\in B$.

How do I include the measure preserving to come to some kind of conclusion?

Attempt 2:

for $f=\chi_A$ and $A$ measurable so $T^{-1}(A)$ is measurable:

$$
f(T(x))\leq f(x) \implies \chi_{T^{-1}(A)}(x)=\chi_A(T(x))\leq \chi_A(x)
$$
As the indicator fuction of measurable sets are integrable:

$$
\int_X\chi_{T^{-1}(A)}(x)d\mu=\int_X\chi_A(T(x))d\mu\leq \int_X\chi_A(x)d\mu
$$
$$
\mu(T^{-1}(A))\leq\mu(A)
$$
and by assumption of measure preserving
$$
\mu(A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A))\leq\mu(A)
$$
Thus, all are equal.

Then the next step for $f=\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i\chi_{A_i}$ with $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{R_{\geq0}}$ and then $f=f^+-f^-$

Comment: This is not an attempt. Incidentally, how do you know that $f\circ T$ is integrable?

Comment: Oh, yes I do not. Then what I stated is not correct.

Comment: Right, so you need to use the invariance. Presumably you know how to do it for $f=\chi_A$. You need to depart from there, that's the exercise. Note that the notion of "measure preserving" is not correct.

Comment: I added my next attempt. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Exactly, you only need to add constants to the sum (you want to get all simple functions). The (possibly) delicate part is to go to $f^+-f^-$.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

$\int |f(Tx)|d\mu =\int |f| d\mu < \infty$. Now $g(x)=f(x)-f(T(x))$ is non-negative and its integral is 0. Hence $g=0$ a.e. which is what you want.

Comment: Just to note that in the book of Brin and Stuck the notion of invariance is not shown to be equivalent to what you mention (although we all know that it is). The exercise is precisely requiring to show this. So you cannot use it here.